# Bluemix Crash on Next Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, ibm-cloud

Does anyone know why NodeJS instances crash on a Next tick or Mongoose pre error? What are some ideas to create a more stable application as we work to identify all errors?  Is IBM planning more resiliency?

I guess we could just create a Linux docker image and run node from there - but that defies the point of these independent instances.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the errors got and especially the context these are happening?

Comment: This is the typical error that causes the Bluemix instance to crash: 2015-11-27T10:46:57.924-0500[App/1]ERR throw new Error("Your pre must have a next argument -- e.g., f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have implemented the mongoose middelware function for brcypting the password :

```
userSchema.pre('save', function validate(next) {
var user = this;

if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        user.password = hash;

        next();
        // done();
    });
});
});
```

This is controlled by the "hooks" module in nom-mongoose.

I tried to create the same error on my end and I was able to raise the same error if I don't pass any arguments to the function validate(...

This means on Bluemix, the next/done arguments used are not passed and received by the hooks module, otherwise it works fine on every machine.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen examples of MEAN stack applications using Node.js + Mongoose using a style of resilient connection code based on the fact that when MongoDB service is stopped, an error event is triggered, but the *connection.readyState* is still 1 (connected). For this reason it didn't auto reconnect. Considering this you could use timeouts to ensure resiliency.

Please refer to [this post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/c1b14989-1f61-4411-a56c-abcde2481218/entry/How_to_Make_a_resilient_connection_between_Node_js_and_MongoDB_using_Mongoose_in_Bluemix?lang=en) to see how you can reconnect on disconnections.

However, please consider that this should be only a way to help you (as you correctly said) while you work to identify all errors, rather than a definitive solution.

Moreover, please note that the example above uses MongoLab Service, that is no more present in the Bluemix catalog. I suggest you to use MongoDB by Compose service instead.

Using Bluemix PaaS then you should scale horizontally to ensure availability of your nodes.

Comment: It has nothing to do with MongoLab - I believe it's all to do with error handling within Bluemix. If this error occurs: 2015-11-27T10:46:57.924-0500[App/1]ERR throw new Error("Your pre must have a next argument -- e.g., f | the app crashes. 2015-11-27T10:46:57.924-0500[App/1]ERR/home/vcap/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:58
2015-11-27T10:46:57.924-0500[App/1]ERR at ObjectId.SchemaType.doValidate (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:654:22)

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing is prefaced by [App/1], which indicates that the message is coming from instance "1" of your application.  Your specific error is coming from the Node.js runtime that is running your application.  This leads me to believe that the error causing your application to crash is due to some faulty code -- the crash would happen in any environment, not just Bluemix.

Bluemix doesn't do any special error handling. If your application throws an error and crashes, Bluemix will try to restart the application for you.  Other than that, there is no special logic to catch or handle application level errors.  During execution of your application, if the Node.js runtime runs into an error and crashes, then the Bluemix application will also crash.

The stack trace you posted in the other comment indicates a problem with how your 'mongoose' middleware is setup... possibly a lack of a `next` function which causes your database request to hang?

Comment: Sai - it is next and pre handling, but it does not crash in any other environment. Such as if I were running Node on a standalone Linux instance - the application would continue. This is what's concerning to me that, albeit not perfect code, the instance shouldn't crash.